Evaluate a Null variable in a YAML build?
I want to have a boolean passed into a task in the Azure DevOps YAML build if a variable is not populated.
I have created a job variable:
isPreRelease: $[ ne(dependencies.SetupStage.outputs['ConfigJob.VersionOut.releaseTag'], '') ]
But this evaluates to false instead of the desired true...
The logs show it trying to evaluate Null to '' (empty string) and the understandable result is False.
  isPreRelease:
    Parsing expression: <ne(dependencies.SetupStage.outputs['ConfigJob.VersionOut.releaseTag'], '')>
    Evaluating: ne(dependencies['SetupStage']['outputs']['ConfigJob.VersionOut.releaseTag'], '')
    Expanded: ne(Null, '')
    Result: 'False'

How can I evaluate that if ConfigJob.VersionOut.releaseTag is Null then we get True?

Did any of the below answers help you solve your problem?

The coalesce function can be used to return the first value that doesn't equal null or empty-string.
Example:
coalesce(variables.couldBeNull, variables.couldAlsoBeNull, 'default value')


How can I evaluate that if ConfigJob.VersionOut.releaseTag is Null then we get True?

Try something like this:
coalesce(dependencies.SetupStage.outputs['ConfigJob.VersionOut.releaseTag'], 'True')

Full expression:
variables:
  isPreRelease: $[ ne(coalesce(dependencies.SetupStage.outputs['ConfigJob.VersionOut.releaseTag'], 'True'), '') ]


From the document, the correct format is as the following:

Set an output variable for use in future jobs:

      variables:
        myVarFromJobA: $[ dependencies.JobName.outputs['TaskName.myOutputVar'] ] 


Set an output variable for use in future stages:

    variables:
      myStageAVar: $[stageDependencies.StageName.JobName.outputs['TaskName.myOutputVar']] 

Your format seems wrong:
    isPreRelease: $[ ne(dependencies.SetupStage.outputs['ConfigJob.VersionOut.releaseTag'], '') ]
    isPreRelease: $[ ne(dependencies.StageName.outputs['JobName.TaskName.myOutputVar'], '') ]

This causes that the value is always empty which shows Null when the pipeline evaluates it.
Please refer the following yaml with the correct format of an output variable for use in future jobs/stages
trigger:
- none

stages:
- stage: SetupStage
  jobs:
  - job: ConfigJob
    steps:
    - bash: |
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=releaseTag;isoutput=true]TagValue"
      name: VersionOut
  - job: JobB
    dependsOn: ConfigJob
    variables:
      isPreRelease: $[ ne(dependencies.ConfigJob.outputs['VersionOut.releaseTag'] , '') ]
    steps:
    - bash: |
        echo isPreRelease $(isPreRelease)
- stage: StageB
  dependsOn: SetupStage
  jobs:
  - job: JobB1
    variables:
      isPreRelease: $[ ne(stageDependencies.SetupStage.ConfigJob.outputs['VersionOut.releaseTag'] , '') ]
    steps:
    - bash: |
        echo isPreRelease $(isPreRelease)

Test result:
Use the Variable in future Job:
Variables:
  isPreRelease:
    Parsing expression: <ne(dependencies.ConfigJob.outputs['VersionOut.releaseTag'] , '')>
    Evaluating: ne(dependencies['ConfigJob']['outputs']['VersionOut.releaseTag'], '')
    Expanded: ne('TagValue', '')
    Result: 'True'

Use the Variable in future Stage:
Variables:
  isPreRelease:
    Parsing expression: <ne(stageDependencies.SetupStage.ConfigJob.outputs['VersionOut.releaseTag'] , '')>
    Evaluating: ne(stageDependencies['SetupStage']['ConfigJob']['outputs']['VersionOut.releaseTag'], '')
    Expanded: ne('TagValue', '')
    Result: 'True'

When you set the releaseTag value to "Null" in the VersionOut task ( echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=releaseTag;isoutput=true]Null"):
Variables:
  isPreRelease:
    Parsing expression: <ne(dependencies.ConfigJob.outputs['VersionOut.releaseTag'] , '')>
    Evaluating: ne(dependencies['ConfigJob']['outputs']['VersionOut.releaseTag'], '')
    Expanded: ne('Null', '')
    Result: 'True'

When you didn't set the releaseTag value (skip the VersionOut task), the variable is not populated:
Variables:
  isPreRelease:
    Parsing expression: <ne(dependencies.ConfigJob.outputs['VersionOut.releaseTag'] , '')>
    Evaluating: ne(dependencies['ConfigJob']['outputs']['VersionOut.releaseTag'], '')
    Expanded: ne(Null, '')
    Result: 'False'

The two Nulls are different. One is string 'Null', the other is Null which means it is empty.
The variable isPreRelease is set to true when the releaseTag value is specified in the VersionOut task, and it is false when the releaseTag is not set.
